# xargs on retaining filename for batch html to text conversion

Tags: bash, find, html-parsing, xargs

I'm converting some html files to text using html2text and want to retain the name of the file name *charliesheenwinning.html* as *charliesheenwinning.txt* or even *charliesheenwinning.html.txt* .

```
find ./ -not -regex ".*\(png\|jpg\|gif\)$" -print0 | xargs -0 -L10 {} max-process=0 html2text {} -o ../potistotallywinning/{}.txt
```

Of course the last part -o is so wrong. How do I retain reusing the filename beyond the first argument to html2text? Can use a for in -exec, but how can I do it with xargs?

**update**

Ended up doing

```
find path/to/dir -type f -not -regex ".*\(gif\|png\|jpg\|jpeg\|mov\|pdf\|txt\)$" -print0 | xargs -0 -L10 --max-procs=0 -I {} html2text -o {}.txt {}
mkdir dir/w/textfiles
cp -r path/to/dir dir/w/textfiles
find dir/w/textfiles -type f -not -regex ".*txt$" -print0 | xargs -0 -L10 --max-procs=0 -I {} rm {}
```

Not the best .. but whatever.. 
[just in case you were wondering why it isn't just a simple -name '*html' in the find argument, this was a wget of a mediawiki .. ]

Comment: If you're webscraping Wikimedia, be aware they have an API that's better to use: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API

Comment: @Vamana thanks for the pointer ... would it allow a non-admin(without db access) to extract text content?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use basename:

```
$ man basename
```

Comment: xargs doesn't process its command via the shell unless you tell it to (`xargs sh -c ...`), and then you may have quoting issues.  Easiest is to create a small shell script to do what needs to be done and invoke it form `xargs`.

Comment: @geekosaur ... yeah I'm trying to that, but the problem is passing the filename from xargs to that command. xargs -0 -L10 {} max-process=0 sh -c "html2text '{}' > '{}.txt'"
xargs: {}: No such file or directory

Comment: I suspect that's because you're using the wrong `xargs` syntax; as written, you are trying to execute a command named `{}` with parameters `'max-process=0' 'sh' '-c' "html2text '{}' > '{}.txt'.  What exactly were you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: Just make it simple and stupid using a for loop: `for i in \`find ./ -type f -not -regex ".*\(png\|jpg\|gif\)$"\`; do html2text $i -o \`basename $i .html\`.txt; done;` but there will be a bad interaction between `".*\(png\|jpg\|gif\)$"` and `\`basename $i .html\`.txt`.

Comment: Uh ...had missed the -I in xargs

Comment: @Renaud .. that works, but I just wanted to throw in all CPU to it :P, because there are tonnes of html files ...

Comment: Wrap your command with `nice` if you want to put it on an uniline.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem – for the record, here's what I came up with to get substition into xargs:

```
seq 100 | xargs -I % -n 1 -P 16 bash -c 'echo % `sed "s/1/X/" <<< %`'
```

It will print something like this:

```
10 X0
3 3
12 X2
4 4
11 X1
1 X
15 X5
```